# Transform Excel into vector in the Graphic Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have a graphic modeler with two inputs, a shapefile and an Excel file.
I would like to make a join by attribute between the two. But I am confronted with a concern, the join can only do this between two vectors, and I cannot transform the Excel file into a vector.

---

The goal is to call my excel file, see attachment

[image]

Comment: There's a difference between a *join* and a *spatial join*. Only the latter requires two geometry sources.

Comment: Hi. I have changed my answer to make more clear the different steps to follow to create the model as you want to do, working with a CSV file (Excel file). I hope now is more clear and suit your request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a model to join one CSV file and one shapefile without adding the CSV file (Excel file) in the map, you can create a model using two Vector layer inputs.

The CSV (Excel file) file is added  creating a Vector Layer with this parameters:

[image]

The second input will be your shapefile added as Vector layer.

This is the result:

[image]

When you run the model, where is requested the Excel file click in the icon in the left (as in image) and navigate to your file.

[image]

Your output file will be a vector with the joined attributes.

Comment: I put the answer above